# align imageview to the corner of the relarivelayout

Tags: android-studio, imageview

I want to keep resize_btn image in the lower right corner of the relativelayout

I tried ForegroundGravity but it did nothing.

I wonder if there is any way to keep the image in the bottom right corner

[image]

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/expanded_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expandedclose_btn"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/close"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expandedresize_btn"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/collapse"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/resize_btn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
            android:src="@drawable/resize"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update resize_btn like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/resize_btn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:src="@drawable/resize"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" 

        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```